# What is the upside versus downside of Nginx image caching?

Tags: caching, nginx

Could anyone please clarify for me the effect of Nginx caching image?

Currently I am using dedicated server. Static images are stored in one folder and used for articles. The library increases in size about 500 images every day, and server hits around 800k pages/day. Each page has around 4 big images.

Server disks are in RAID 1.

I'm have issues with Nginx caching. The HDD becomes full so quickly that the server stops running.  I have to restart Nginx service to make Nginx clear the cache again.

I was thinking of removing the cache images config (especially `.jpg`) from Nginx, because I think this config doesn't help server anyway.

Since static images are stored in one folder, I applied `ExpiresActive` to header. So what do I need Nginx for?

From downside I see wasted HDD volume, spent resources of CPU and RAM while reading those images again and again then writing to cache.

Please tell me what benefits I will have by using Nginx cache image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend not to cache any images (or any static content). Nginx is already efficient in serving static content from the disk.

PS: I can't comment. So, writing it as an answer. Thanks.